# How to name the out put of nested for loop with unique names in R studio?

Tags: r, nested-loops

I am trying to reorganize my data in a certain way to produce new data for different criteria. I ended up implementing 3 nested loops to do that. It worked but I have a problem storing the data uniquely. Please, keep in mind that the out needs to be stored in a data frame form. Here is what I did and I am looking for your feedback.

```
for (i in 1:4){
    for (j in 0:20){
    for(k in seq(from = 00, to = 45, by = 15)){
            DFBB <- filter(cd3d1, friend's== h[i], numberofcars == j , money == k)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what's in `cd3d1` in order to properly help. The problem right now is that you're storing different things over and over in the same object `DFBB`, so you'd end up with whatever is done last.

Comment: For are all possible combination of unique values of columns, consider `split` to save in a list of data frames: `df_list <- split(cd3d1, list(cd3d1$friends, cd3d1$numberofcars, cd3d1$money))`